# Can a Python object attribute have its own attribute?

Tags: python, object, attributes

I'm a little confused by what I'm seeing in the unittest file of this Exercism exercise. These are some of the tests that are run to check the validity of my program. (You create a PhoneNumber object in the main program.)

```
    def test_area_code(self):
        number = PhoneNumber("2234567890")
        self.assertEqual(number.area_code, "223")

    def test_pretty_print(self):
        number = PhoneNumber("2234567890")
        self.assertEqual(number.pretty(), "(223) 456-7890")

    def test_pretty_print_with_full_us_phone_number(self):
        number = PhoneNumber("12234567890")
        self.assertEqual(number.pretty(), "(223) 456-7890")
```

I know how to create the `number` attribute for my class objects, but what do `number.area_code` and `number.pretty()` mean? What makes this valid Python code? I tried just creating a value like `self.number.area_code = <something here>`, but that didn't work. What exactly is this called and how do I create it?

Thanks!

Edit: This is another part of the unittest file:

```
def test_cleans_the_number(self):
        number = PhoneNumber("(223) 456-7890").number
        self.assertEqual(number, "2234567890")

    def test_cleans_numbers_with_dots(self):
        number = PhoneNumber("223.456.7890").number
        self.assertEqual(number, "2234567890")

    def test_cleans_numbers_with_multiple_spaces(self):
        number = PhoneNumber("223 456   7890   ").number
        self.assertEqual(number, "2234567890")
```

Doesn't this part mean that `number` is an attribute? This is why I misunderstood the previously quoted section. The unittest file seems to be using `number` in two different ways, and I didn't catch it in the former part!

Comment: `number` isn't an attribute. But in any case, if you see something like `some_object.some_attribute.some_other_attribute` taht simply means that `some_object.some_attribute` evaluates to an object with a `.some_other_attribute` attribute. Note, *everything* is an object in Python. So `number.area_code` is the `area_code` attribute of whatever the variable `number` refers to, in this case, a `PhoneNumber` object

Comment: I am not sure if you really do know how to create number as an attribute of your class.  In this code, "number" is the name of an instance of PhoneNumber.  "area_code" is the name of an attribute of the PhoneNumber class, and "pretty" is the name a function defined in the PhoneNumber class.  If your class code doesn't define an attribute named "area_code" and a function named "pretty" this test code will fail.  There is no requirement for "number" to be an attribute of PhoneNumber.

Comment: Ugh, I misread the unittest code then! Thanks guys! Sorry for my confusion!

Comment: Ah, let me post another part of the unittest real quick:

```class PhoneNumberTest(unittest.TestCase):  
        def test_cleans_the_number(self):  
            number = PhoneNumber("(223) 456-7890").number  
            self.assertEqual(number, "2234567890")```

In this instance, isn't `number` being used as an attribute for a PhoneNumber object? This is how it's used in most of the unittest, *except* for the part I quoted in my original question.

Comment: @JohnSalerno don't add code to comments, edit your question anf format it in there

Comment: Sorry. I thought the Markdown would make it look nice, but it definitely didn't! Edited the original post.

Comment: So yeah, `Phone(...).number` is trying to access a `number` attribute on the `Phone` object. But in the other tests, `number` was simply the name of a local variable. There's an old quip "There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things."